# Julialang: error ` ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to open libLLVM!` when llvm is installed

Tags: julia

I am still new to the `Julia` language, but ran into a strange error. So I am trying to precompile and load a package called `Sympy.jl` for symbolic mathematics like the eponymous Python package.

I have Julia 1.0.0 installed, and ran the code from the package manager:

```
build SpecialFunctions;
```

as this is a dependency for the `Sympy` package. I am getting an error that says:

```
 ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to open libLLVM!
```

Now, I checked the julia `versioninfo()` command and it shows that LLVM is installed. Not sure why it says I am using red-hat linux when I am using Ubuntu. Here is the output.

```
Julia Version 1.0.0
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6850K CPU @ 3.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, broadwell)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I googled around about all references to similar issues have to do with earlier versions of Julia, so was not sure what applied anymore.

Comment: Did you install Julia with a package manager? If so, could you try official Generic Linux binaries from https://julialang.org/downloads/ and see if the problem persists?

Comment: This issue suggests it has been fixed in Julia v1.0.1: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29720

Comment: The marked solution seemed to work for me. I am using the source bundle from the github repo, so the issue might be fixed. But seems this symlink was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you have libLLVM.so in your path. If not, and LLVM is installed, then create a simlink to the library:
`on ubuntu:
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libLLVM.6.0.so.1 /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/libLLVM.so`

Comment: Okay, this seems to have worked. Thanks so much. I created the symlink, and then I also added the folder to my PATH variable. And then I was able to build ZMQ. Thanks so much. Did I miss this step somewhere in the install documentation or something?